# Запятая перед И: "Он пишет письмо Христиане(,) и в нем задорную фразу:..."

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Чем объясняется запятая перед "и" в данном предложении?

"Тотчас после ее отъезда он пишет письмо в Веймар Христиане, и в нем задорную фразу:..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бог знает,что имел автор в виду,может,присоединение (скорее всего), может,второе предложение в сложносочинённом оформил как неполное. Во всяком случае здесь хочется по интонации её поставить, я бы тоже поставила. Иногда там ещё и тире ставят:..."и в нем -задорную фразу..."

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Что значит "присоединение"?
Вторая часть и есть неполная: пропущен глагол. Интересно только узнать, какой именно логикой или правилом здесь нужно было руководствоваться, чтобы поставить запятую. В случае с тире все бы было логично.

Есть еще подобный пример. Из Пушкина (формулировка не точная):
"Дед бил меня, и все палкой".

Comment: Я имею в виду присоединительный оборот, у Пушкина точно он:
http://www.lingvotech.com/prisoed. http://licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_2_8

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это прояснило ситуацию.

Answer (score 0):

Союз "и" объединяет части сложного сложного предложения.

Comment: О каком сложном предложении Вы вообще говорите? Тут предложение, вне всякого сомнения, является простым.

Comment: Но разве "письмо" и "задорная фраза" не равноправные части, которые обе связаны с одним и тем же глаголом ("пишет")?